# How to count number in certain line?

Tags: python, file, sum

I am reading a file from textfile.

Text File:

```
Mike
2006
1

Dylan
2007
1

Ben
2007
1

English
2008
1

James
2008
0
```

How do I count the total number in each year?

For example, in 2006 there is only 1, 2007 there is only 2, 2008 there is only 1.

code:

```
f = open("file.txt")
    for line in f:
        readFile = line.strip();
        print(readFile)
    f.close()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can figure it out with this :

```
temp=[]
def count_year_num(year):
    f = open("test.txt")
    lines=''.join(list(f))
    newgrouping=lines.split('\n\n') # grouping the content of file result is like this : ['Mike\n2006\n1', 'Dylan\n2007\n1', 'Ben\n2007\n1', 'English\n2008\n1', 'James\n2008\n0\n']

    newgrouping= [i.split('\n') for i in newgrouping] #splite the grouped content :[['Mike', '2006', '1'], ['Dylan', '2007', '1'], ['Ben', '2007', '1'], ['English', '2008', '1'], ['James', '2008', '0', '']]

    for i in newgrouping:
        if year in i:
            temp.append(int(i[2])) # append the numbers to a temp list
    return sum(temp) # find the sum of number
```

Demo :

```
>>>count_year_num('2008')
1
>>>count_year_num('2007')
2
```

Comment: That counts the number of appearances of `count`, which isn't what he's asking for unfortunately. He's looking to add up the associated numbers (e.g. there are two occurrences of `2008`, but the sum for `2008` is `1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=defaultdict(int)
>>> with open('file','r') as f:
...     while True:
...             if not f.readline():
...                     break
...             key=f.readline().strip()
...             value=f.readline().strip()
...             a[key] = a[key] + int(value)
...             if not f.readline():
...                     break

>>> dict(a)
{'2008': 1, '2006': 1, '2007': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a regular expression to extract the year. This only works if years are the only for digit numbers in your text.
First, read the whole text into a variable:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Next extract all the years using a regular expression. This will return a list of matches:

```
lst = re.findall("\d{4}", text)
```

Last step is to populate a dictionary using the years as keys and values are the number of occurrences:

```
d = {}
for year in lst:
    if year in d:
        d[year] +=1
    else:
        d[year] = 1
```

The dictionary 'd' can now be queried for the number of occurrences of year in the text:

```
print d['2007'] # prints 2
```